# Adding Menu doesn't work, android, HTC One M8

Tags: android, menu

Menu options doesn't show up on HTC One M8. In my old HTC phone, press and hold multitasking button was opening menu. In HTC One M8 I suppose to see 3 dot menu button when an app does have a menu option, but I don't.

Just simple menu implementation:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and the items are added like this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuButton1"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/menuButton1"
    android:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Any implementation I should follow to make it visible?

Comment: Sidenote (doesn't solve your problem, just FIY): On the HTC One you can open the menu by long pressing the home button in apps that don't use the action bar.

Comment: Not in HTC One M8, it only works in M7

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the support for the actionbar by extending ActgionBarActivity instead of Activity.